# how to deduce the indicator of the transition from one state to another?

Tags: sql

I have a column that only contains 1 and 0. If 1 is a bona fide payer, if 0 is an unscrupulous one. Each customer has data for January 31st, February 29th and March 31st (all 2016).
It turns out like this:

```
2016-01-31   1
2016-02-29   1
2016-03-31   0
```

How can I display an indicator characterizing the presence of at least one transition from a bona fide payer to an unscrupulous one in 3 months?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Can you add some more sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily with `LAG` window function, which allow you to access the information of the previous row, according to de order you define.

So, assuming your customer is identified by `cust_id`, that your date is called `date_eval` and your indicator `indic`, you would have something like this to identify dates where there are changes:

```sql
with calc_changes as (
    select cust_id, date_eval, 
           case when LAG(indic) OVER (ORDER BY date_eval) = indic then 1
                else 0
           end as is_changed
      from your_table
)
select * 
 from calc_changes
 where is_changed = 1
```